# Making a query with two columns computed from data in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started checking SQL server in my work, and I just can´t manage to solve this very easy thing.

Lets say I have this Table:

```
Model   Serial Pass   Failure  
Y72742  LURC1   0     Ref 5
Y72742  LURC2   0     Ref 10
Y72596  JDID1   1     EMT
Y72596  JDID2   1     EMT
Y72742  LURC3   0     Ref 10
Y72596  JDID3   0     Ref 5
Y72596  JDID4   0     Ref 18
Y72596  JDID5   1     EMT
Y72596  JDID6   0     Ref 18
Y72596  JDID7   0     Ref 5
Y72596  LURC4   1     UMT
Y72596  LURC5   1     UMT
```

So in the PASS column, the 1 means the unit passed, the 0 means it failed. The Failure Column indicates what was the failure.

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
Model   Pass   Failed   Percentage
Y72742   2       3         40%
Y72596   1       4         20%
```

But since is the same column I just can't get it done.

I tried with a subquery with the "AND" operator, but I got errors. if anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

Regards.

Comment: what does the porcentage mean ?

Comment: Pass rate 2 out of 5 is 40%, not 66%

Comment: And 1 out of 5 is 20%, not 25%.

Comment: The porcentage is the porcentage of units that passes vs the total, I looks like I made a mistake but dasblinkenlight and Ken help me fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct your query using `SUM` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    Model
,   SUM(case when Pass=1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) AS Pass
,   SUM(case when Pass=1 then 0.0 else 1.0 end) AS Failed
,   100*SUM(case when Pass=1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end)/COUNT(*) AS Percentage
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Model
```

Comment: I put this:

  SELECT
    PartNum
,   SUM(Pass) AS Pass
,   SUM(1-Pass) AS Failed
/*   100.0*SUM(Pass)/COUNT(*) AS Percentage*/
FROM [RceTestwareMfrLog].[dbo].[RceLogData]
GROUP BY PartNum

And I get this error:

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: @LuisFernandoQuiñónez Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: You beautiful bastard, you did it!, I wasn´t sure but you actually did it, thank you so very much, you made my day. Have a happy life. :)

Comment: @LuisFernandoQuiñónez You are welcome! If you do not need further help with the question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This will let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and earn you a badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Done, I spend 5 minutos looking for the check mark lol, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL implementation:

```
SELECT 
t.Model, 
SUM(IF(t.Pass=1,1,0)) as Passed, 
SUM(IF(t.Pass=0,1,0)) as Failed,
SUM(IF(t.Pass=1,1,0))/COUNT(t.Pass) as Percentage
FROM MyTable t 
GROUP BY t.Model
```

Comment: Hi, I put this SELECT 
PartNum 
SUM(IF(t.Pass=1,1,0)) as Passed, 
SUM(IF(t.Pass=0,1,0)) as Failed,
SUM(IF(t.Pass=1,1,0))/COUNT(t.Pass) as Percentage
FROM [RceTestwareMfrLog].[dbo].[RceLogData] t 
GROUP BY t.Model  

And the error I get is this:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: I was fooled by the MySQL tag in your question. For MS SQL Server the correct syntax is given in @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: Sorry about the tag, I´m pretty new to this, and I honestly don´t know the difference beetwen them, was my mistake. Also I want to thank you for the time you spend helping me.

Regards.